# GraphQL only fetch if certain field is requested in query

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server

A very basic schema:

```
type Foo {
    id: String!
    name: String!
    createdAt: Date!
    bars: [Bar]
}

type Bar {
    id: String!
    name: String!
    fooId: String!
}
```

Then my Resolver map:

```
Query: {
    foo: 
      async (
        _: any,
        { id }: { id: string }
      ) => {

        const { data: fooObj } = await httpRequest({
          url: `/api/foos/${id}`
        });

        const barsResponse = await httpRequest({
          url: `/api/bars/?fooId=${id}`
        });
        const response = {
          ...fooObj.foo,
          bars: barsResponse.data.bars
        };
        return response;
      }
 }
```

If the user does the following query:

```
{
  foo(id: "123456"){
    bars {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

The the Query resolver correctly fetches and returns the right data in the right shape, however, running this query:

```
{
  foo(id: "123456"){
    name
  }
}
```

Ideally wouldn't do the 2nd fetch request to get the `bars`. How can I split the Query Resolver up so it only runs the Bars fetch if the query contains `bars`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, move the fetching logic into the resolver for `bars`:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    foo: () => {...},
  },
  Foo: {
    bars: ({ id }) => {
      const { data: { bars } } = await httpRequest({
        url: `/api/bars/?fooId=${id}`
      })
      return bars
    },
  },
}
```

The first parameter passed to every resolver is the value the parent field resolved to. As long as what's returned inside the resolver for `Query.foo` includes the `id`, this will be available to the resolver for `Foo.bars`.

A field's resolver is not called unless that field is requested (and the parent field doesn't resolve to null). So your call to `/api/bars` will only be triggered if the field is present in the request.

It's also possible to continue fetching everything at the root level if you like. The fourth parameter passed to the resolver is a `GraphQLResolveInfo` object that will include information about the request, including which fields were requested. You can parse this object and have your root resolver behave accordingly. For simpler scenarios like this, though, that's overkill.